# In my team, even I don't know any information of android, they give me a homework to make a adapter. What is that?

Tags: android, android-adapter

It's first time to install the android studio. I don't know what is layout, or R or something structures and so on. and I got a mission to make a adapter . What is adapter and how I get complete making adapter. please help me.

Comment: Google for 'android adapter'.

Comment: It's a bad idea of directly asking for help without trying anything. Please have some search on Google later ask if you are facing a specific problem.

Comment: You could start here: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: thanks alot! I know trying is important. after I face some specific problems , I will be back!

Answer (score 0):

Read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html
Official documentation will help you.

Another good article
http://www.edureka.co/blog/what-are-adapters-in-android/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So layout is where your design is it is where you design your app. R represents the Res file which is resource file. Inside the Res file you have your design and images that you want to use for your app. Basically everything you need will be inside the Res file.